# Why does Oracle think I'm missing a right parenthesis?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

In Oracle 10i, I'm running the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE jnrvwchnglst ADD
     ( jnrvwchnglst_userid NUMBER(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 )
```

Yes `jnrvwchnglst` is an existing table and no `jnrvwchnglst_userid` is not an existing column.

The Oracle error message is:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

What's wrong with this query and why does Oracle think I'm missing a parenthesis?

Comment: Not that it's my business, but what on Earth do you keep in table with such a name? Junior Volkswagens Change List? :)

Comment: @Quassnoi - The ORM system removes vowels from tokens because Oracle has its (unreasonable) 30-char maximum.  So really that's "JoinReviewChangelist."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE jnrvwchnglst ADD
     ( jnrvwchnglst_userid NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 1  NOT NULL )
```

Answer (score 4):

"(NOT) NULL" must be the last statement in the "ALTER" syntactically when present, so when Oracle saw that - and that the next char (your "DEFAULT" stmt) wasn't the expected terminating right ")", threw the error.

Comment: Hopefully this explains more WHY u got the error, to help solve other like scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before where you can't add a column AND set the default/constraints in the same statement.  The 'missing right parenthesis' is a red-herring.  Oracle loves to use that error for cases that are unrelated to parenthesis (My guess is that their parsing logic falls through to 00907).

Try

```
ALTER TABLE jnrvwchnglst ADD ( nrvwchnglst_userid NUMBER(10) );
ALTER TABLE jnrvwchnglst ALTER ( nrvwchnglst_userid  SET DEFAULT 1 );
UPDATE jnrvwchnglst SET nrvwchnglst_userid = 1 WHERE nrvwchnglst_userid IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE jnrvwchnglst  ALTER ( nrvwchnglst_userid  SET NOT NULL );
```

Comment: Darn it =)  Or it could just be an order of operations issue.  bah =)

Comment: That's true with e.g. TIMESTAMP.  However Quassnoi's code does work.  Thanks!